# How can i do the integration with the exponential terms?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, change-of-variable

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$\int \frac{\gamma F ^ {-3/2} + F ^ {-\beta/2}} {3\gamma F^ {-3/2} + \beta F^ {-\beta/2}} d\varphi$

where $\beta$, $\gamma$ are constant and $F$ is:

$F=1+\frac{\beta-3}{3}\bigg(2\gamma(\beta-1)e^{-(\frac{1+\beta}{\sqrt{6}})\varphi}+\frac{2}{3}(\beta-2)(\beta+3)e^{2(\frac{1-\beta}{\sqrt{6}})\varphi}\bigg)$

does anyone has a solution for this integration?

Comment: If $\beta=3$ then the integral equals $\frac{\varphi}{3}$. That's the best I can do.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi No, $\beta=3$ is trivial and we are not allowded to fix our own $\beta$

Comment: What is the no for? Was my statement incorrect?

Comment: I said no because we are not allowed to fix the value of $\beta$ as 3. It is led to a singularity in the system under consideration.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a closed form for this?  I doubt there is.